Adding external javascript + css files to Angular app
No dev guru here. I am an Angular newbie. I have tried solutions from previous SO posts, but they are either outdated or not working.
This is my local configuration:
Windows 10 / Angular CLI 17.2.3 / Node.js 20.11.1
I want to add an audio player to my Angular app.
This is what I have done so far:

put essential_audio.css in src/assets/css and essential_audio.js in src/assets/js
added both css and js files to angular.json (styles and js sections respectively)
imported essential_audio.css into global css file src/styles.css
added the player's div to product-details.component.html

Problem is, when I load product details page in the browser (http://localhost:4200/), the audio player does NOT show up, even though:

essential_audio.css appears inside styles.css in the head section of the product details page
essential_audio.js appears inside scripts.js just before /body tag of the product details page

Will someone please help me fix this?
Thanks for your help.

From the documentation, it seems Essential audio player runs a script on page load and looks for the div element. Angular probably has not yet created your component and the div element when this script runs.
You have to manually initialize the audio player by calling Essential_Audio.init() when your component is ready. Calling it in ngAfterViewInit is probably a good start.
// product-details.component.ts

// Let TypeScript know we have a global variable defined somewhere else.
declare var Essential_Audio: any;

class ProductDetailsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // Intialize Essential audio player when the component view is ready.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    Essential_Audio.init();
}


Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Sorry for my noobiness, should I call Essential_Audio.init() in product-details.component.ts?

I have updated my answer with some example code.

Very kind of you, thanks
